# Зачем нужена вложенная функция в данном случае?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Допустим, имеем объект:

```
let obj = {
  'name': 'Blabo',
  getName: function() {
     return () => {
        console.log('Name is: ' + this.name);
     }
  }
}
```

Зачем мы имеем внутри функции `getName()` функцию `return`? Ясное дело, что решается вопрос видимости `this`, но почему бы не использовать подход проще:

```
  let obj = {
      'name': 'Blabo',
      getName: function() {
         console.log('Name is: ' + this.name);
      }
    }
```

Или передать значение `name` как параметр функции?

Comment: Это касается и javascript-а

Comment: В двух случаях результат одинаковый

Comment: Вопрос в том, как эта функция будет использоваться

Comment: _В двух случаях результат одинаковый_ - не будет, так как один будет возвращать функцию, а второй - ничего не будет возвращать, а сразу выводить в консоль

Comment: имею ввиду результат конечный

Comment: @OPV, про конечный результат и идет речь. В одном случае ты получаешь функцию, ты ее можешь вызвать, а можешь и не вызывать, во втором, ты просто выводишь в console.log сразу без вариантов.

Comment: во втором случае, кажется  не должно быть проблем с контекстом, хотя не уверен